# Progress of mapreduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm developing a MapReduce application and I want to know the progress of the job I'm running. I am already familiar with the job.mapprocess and job.reducerprocess methods. The problem that those methods only works when the job is finished.

Is there any method that give you the progress of the job on real time while the job is running and not only when it finishs.

Comment: you can check the progress in web UI, ip:8088

Answer (score 1):

In the new Hadoop API, you can access the progress value from the Context object in the mapper or reducer class in the following way:

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<Writable, Writable, Writable, Writable> {

    @Override
    public void map(Writable key, Writable value, Mapper<Writable, Writable, Writable, Writable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        context.getProgress();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean programmatic access then you need to use JobClient API:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/RunningJob.html

You can submit your job via JobClient:

```
JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(jobConf);
RunningJob job = jobClient.submitJob(jobConf);
float mapProgress = job.mapProgress();
float redProgress = job.reduceProgress();
```

Or can look up existing job:

```
JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(jobConf);
RunningJob job = jobClient.getJob("your_job_id");
...
```